# Help identifying software

Tags: sound, spectrogram

I have a small youtube channel and I was interested in a music making software I used a long time ago but I don't know its name, so I thought you could help me :)

The software consist of a rectangular black canvas where you can paint with a brush, a pencil, a spray... and when you have stuff painted there you press "play" and the colors and shapes you've drawn are interpreted as sounds, so it makes noises. It is not Coagula although it is very similar. Thanks for any help! :D

Comment: @jonhatansmith is there a reason you didn't post this as an answer?  I'll leave it for now since I assume maybe you thought it was too short for a full answer, but if the question only really needs short answers, it is fine to post short answers as an actual answer.  Answering in comments is generally discouraged as it can't be marked as solution and voting doesn't work properly on it.  Comments are also subject to being cleared out periodically.

Comment: Your right I though this was too short, and my answer is more like a proposal than a real answer. Anyway I'll put that as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few guesses:

- [MetaSynth](http://www.uisoftware.com/MetaSynth/index.php)
- [Virtual ANS](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/ans/)
- [HighC](http://highc.org/)

Comment: Sorry for answering five years later! Nope, it's none of these. It was way simpler than that -we used it in music class back in school, with crappy computers. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be [IRCAM's Audiosculpt](http://forumnet.ircam.fr/product/audiosculpt-en/) ?!

Answer (score 0):

It might be iZotope's Iris. It certainly fits the description